# #define strange

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define square(v) v*v
void main()
{
int p=3;
int s=square(++p);
printf("%d %d",s,p);
getch();
}
```

output 
25 5
Why 16 4 is not coming as output?
(Advance thanks)

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605005/evaluate-macro-parameter-once-only for a workaround.

Answer (score 12):

A macro is basically a text copy and paste. Therefore your `++` is being duplicated.

The macro is being expanded as:

```
s = ++p * ++p;
```

That's the danger of macros. (in this case, it also invokes undefined behavior)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is undefined about this?

Comment: There's two `++` in the same statement on the same variable. That's undefined.

Comment: @MGZero The expression has no [sequence points](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sequence_point), so there's no predicting when the pre-increment operations will take effect.

Answer (score 3):

the behavior of

```
++p * ++p
```

is undefined, it depends on the compiler

You may use inline instead

```
inline int square(int p) {
    return p * p;
}
```